# How do not repeat nodes that has the same code in diferent paths

Tags: node-red

I am new with Node-Red and I have the next question:

I have a flow that in every http in paths (/home, /global, /add) I have to check if the user is connected. This means I have to repeat the authentication nodes and other stuff for every path. But I was thinking: How can I do it for not repeat it? By the way the real project has like 30 paths, I said this 3 only like example.

The only solution I thought is make links and save one variable for know which one link is for every path. But I am pretty sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subflows

Subflows let you select a collection of nodes and turn them into a reusable group (that gets added to the palette as a new node).

When you edit a subflow it changes all the instances of that subflow.

You create a subflow by selecting the nodes you want to reuse and then from the top right hand menu, select subflows and then create.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I need it!!